# Angularjs - $location.path / $location.url changes URL but doesn't refresh page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Working with Angular and im running into a few issues using $location.url & $location.path

The URL changes at the top of the page to /users/sign_in but I don't see the view until I manually refresh the page, then it appears?

```
function error(response) {
            if (response.status == 401) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('event:unauthorized');
                $location.url('/users/sign_in');
            };
        };
```

I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Did you try with `$location.path('/users/sign_in');`?

Comment: `$location.path`, not `url` should do the trick

Comment: Same thing happens using either .path or .url

Comment: Are you sure there isnt any message on console of browser?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a bit too much in your function.  You're attempting to change the URL but also return a response.  You can try using a `$scope.$apply()` right after the `$location.url` call, however you should consider splitting this logic so that the redirect occurs based on the returned response, or don't return any response from the error function.

Comment: Having the same problem. Any advice?